# Internet explore not visible in Windows features after uninstalling

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser

I uninstalled the internet explorer as it wasn't working properly and thought of reinstalling it.
But after uninsatlling it from windows features I am not able to find it again in there. This is a work computer and I cant reinstall windows or update it. Please give suggestions on how to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned which OS you are using?

If you are using Windows 10 OS then you can try to refer steps below.

(1) Search for 'Optional features' in search box.

(2) It will show an option 'Manage optional features'. Click on it.

(3) Click on 'Add a feature' option.

(4) Find Internet Explorer 11 from the list and click on it.

(5) Click on install button.

Let me know, if you are using any other OS.

If you get any error while installing it and installation get failed then you may need to contact your IT department.

Comment: @Anon Bee, can you please inform the status for this issue? If above answer solved the issue, then please try to accept the answer. If you found the solution by yourself then try to post your solution as an answer. If issue still persist then let us know about the current status for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It has disappeared from optional features

Comment: Did you try to find it by clicking 'See optional feature history'? if not you can try and let us know about the result. If your machine's security policies are controlled by the administrator then you need to contact your administrator to help you to again install the IE 11 browser.